# How to programmatically show modal in a UINavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

In my app, I have a UINavigationController that i'm pushing and popping ViewControllers from.  At some point, I want to show a VC modally (showing the previous controller "underneath"). I can get it to work by setting up a segue in a storyboard, however I'm in a spot where I need to do it programmatically, and I can't seem to find the right magic incantation to make it work.

I saw a couple of similar questions but they seemed to be showing the UINavigationController modally, not showing one of the VC's on the UINavigationController stack modally.

(I put up a test application here:  https://github.com/SuperTango/ModalNavController, and that's where this code and images come from)

The "Manual" code does:

```
@IBAction func goToVC2Tapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2ViewController") as! VC2ViewController
    destinationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    self.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)
}
```

but it's not working (see the second transition in the gif below).

The segue that works is setup like this:

[image: segue setup]

This gif is from the test app and shows how it works with the segue, but  not manually.

[image]

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To present modally you need to use:

```
present(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: { })
```

Comment: Even though I want to present modally, I still want the "VC2" to be pushed  onto the Navigation stack, I don't want to present outside of the navigation stack

Answer (score 0):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVC") as! YourVC

destinationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

destinationViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

self.present(destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

I think this helps show your ViewController in a modal way of presenting. Write the above code under outlet actions or where you want to present your ViewController.